# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror, live-streaming, youtube-data-api

I am working on `YouTube broadcast` sample examples. I have created a sample `Java Project` & added required jars. But, when I try to run the project it throws exception.

Exception :

```
Throwable: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:44)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.live.Auth.<clinit>(Auth.java:35)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.live.CreateBroadcast.main(CreateBroadcast.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
```

I downloaded the project from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java).

Comment: Did you run it using maven?

Comment: looks like com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core dependency is missing in pom.xml

Comment: You missed some jar at runtime that was used at compile time.

Comment: @Nitek No I have added jar by going to project properties option

Comment: @NareshK i am not using Maven

Comment: @FranMontero No, there are no CTE

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using Maven but I downloaded this jar & added to project properties. It worked. Thanks shruti. Accepted + upvoted answer

Comment: I have no idea why this works. I already had version 2.3.3., which is where the error arrrived, but changing the version of (only) jackson-core to 2.5.2. Works.

Comment: I also needed to upgrade jackson dependency to a newer version, but this did not get the name added to my Manifest and therefore ClassNotFoundException was still thrown until I manually edited it.

Answer (score 44):

If you are using springboot then **jackson is added by default**,

So the version of jackson you are adding manualy is probably **conflicting** with the one spring boot adds,

Try to delete the jackson dependencies from your pom,

If you need to override the version spring boots add, then you need to **exclude** it first and then add your own

Comment: how to exclude?

Comment: comment out of your gradle.build - this appears to have worked for me

Comment: Wow, I was following a baeldung tutorial not too long ago, apprently I dont need to add this?, oh well, here goes the hours wasted trying to find the appropriate version to add only to find out that the fix is to remove the jackson related dependencies, ugggh. Thanks.

Comment: I am using Micronaut, not Spring Boot, and this still seems to be the case.

Comment: could you state what module of springboot?

Comment: Thank you bro, this absolutely saved me.

Answer (score 20):

Because of old version I got this error.
Then I changed to this version n error gone 
Using maven
my pom.xml

```
<properties>  
    ...
    <jackson.version>2.5.2</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

my old version was '2.2.3'

Comment: Mine version was 2.9.4. Changed it to latest version 2.9.8 and the error is gone like a magic.

Answer (score 13):

In my case problem was when i added com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat
i put the version **2.11.0**.

While all other Jackson dependencies were 2.8.0 and one of them was **2.11.0** and changing all to be **2.8.0** fixed it.

FYI, 2.11 is the latest but due to my legacy code, i kept it as 2.8 as well.

Before Fix [**ERROR**] : `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat` version is `2.11.0`:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

After Fix [**WORKED**] `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat` version is `2.8.0`:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

I have had the same error.
I added dependency on pom.xml (I am working with Maven)

```
<dependency> 
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId> 
        <version>2.12.1</version> 
 </dependency>
```

I started trying with version 2.9.0, then I found a different error (com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/InputCoercionException)
then I try different versions until all errors were solved with version 2.12.1

Answer (score 5):

The requested jar is probably not jackson-**annotations**-x.y.z.jar but jackson-**core**-x.y.z.jar which could be found here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksoncore220rc1jar.htm

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue by simply removing the version tag as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue was conflicting version of `Jackson-databind`. My spring-boot version was `2.5.8`, and spring-boot was using `jackson-core` version 2.12.6.

My explicit implementation was using `jackson-core` version 2.13.2, and this was the cause of the problem.

I commented out the below line from `gradle.build`, and this fixed the issue.

```yaml
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.13.2'
```

Comment: This give me the hint that the problem was a conflict between versions. I didn't know that spring-boot already have jackson dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Gi1ber7. If the answer has helped your in solving your problem, kindly upvote.  :)

Answer (score 3):

**Solved the problem by upgrading the dependency to below version**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add one jar : `jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar`
You can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonannotations212jar.htm) and add it to the class path
If you are using the  gradle then add the following dependency.

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

As of jackson 2.7.4 (or earlier maybe), the class is in jacskon-jaxrs-base.jar, which is contained in [jackson-jaxrs-json-provider](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider)

Answer (score 2):

I've reproduced the issue like:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeature
```

with version of dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To fix it, I've used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and this was happening due to conflicting Jackson version present in the project.

So I explicitly defined the same version for all the Jackson dependencies in my pom.xml. Post this I did not face the error while running jar and it was properly resolved.

Below is what I used:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Maven Dependency tree with conflicting version**

```
(base) rohiagra-mac:test-secret rohiagra$ mvn dependency:tree|grep jackson
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.32:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9:compile
```

**Maven Dependency tree with resolved conflicts**

```
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.32:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.0:compile
```

Comment: This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most of time it is Jackson version incompatibility. Upgrade the jackson version and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue on my project Java 17, I have used the dependency.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Note that the version of jackson is automatically added by spring boot, you
don't really need to add it manually.

I have removed it from the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding these two dependencies did not help:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

in addition to those, I had to add the following and then it worked:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>foo.bar.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```