Conflicts between WAR file and tomcat lib causing webapp unable to startup due to java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
I came across a problems which is causing my spring webapp unable to start up, the error that showing  is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type , which org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder$XmlObjectMapperInitializer.create() is expecting com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper, but com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper is returned instead, hence App is unabled to startup.
Normally, Tomcat wouldn't need the Jackson module, but because I used the Azure SDK to get credential for Tomcat JDBC pool, Jackson related module is needed, hence I was facing this issue, I will provide stacktrace below.

Tomcat version: 9.0.88
Springboot version: 2.0.4.RELEASE

Azure SDK that was used

azure-security-keyvault-secrets-4.0.0.jar
azure-identity-1.0.0.jar

Jackson dependencies that was used:

jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
jackson-core-2.9.6.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar
jackson-dataformat-xml-2.9.6.jar
jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.6.jar

Kindly refer to attachment for dependencies that was used, and stacktrace.

stacktrace 1
stacktrace 2
stacktrace 3
stacktrace 4
list of dependencies that was included but won't affect

I try import all jackson JAR one by one to see which JAR will cause the app to fail to startup when Azure SDK was not used. So it was found out that jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar was the one that causing this issue. But what I don't understand is that I thought by default, Tomcat dependency shouldn't affect webapp dependency?
As I read from here, it was saying that from the perspective of WAR file, class loader by default will load dependencies from

Bootstrap classes of your JVM
/WEB-INF/classes of your web application
/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
System class loader classes (Tomcat lib)
Common class loader classes (Tomcat additional lib)

Any advice/direction/insight on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, cheers.

Did you already try out the suggestions pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68950481/11464237?
